# How to store array values into php variable

Tags: php, sql

```
$a="SELECT A.Name, SUM(b.NetAmount) AS Total 
    FROM b inner 
    JOIN A ON b.TransTypeID = A.TransTypeID 
    GROUP BY Name ";
$total = mysql_query($a);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($total)){


}
```

How can I store all values into different php variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "all values into different php variables"? Does that mean "store each row in result to different php variable?"

Comment: your question is somewhat lacking , as for your question i think you should use `array()`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to extract key values into separate variables in the local namespace, say, turn this

```
array(
    name1 => val1,
    name2 => val2
)
```

into this

```
$name1 = val1;
$name2 = val2;
```

You can do this with the `extract` function. Here's an example:

```
$arr = array(
    "name1" => 1,
    "name2" => 2
);

extract($arr);

echo $name1;
echo "\n";
echo $name2;

// Output:
// 1
// 2
```

Be warned however that automatically extracting variables into the namespace can lead to very elusive bugs if your codebase gets complex down the line.